# DrawLine width vs. Ellipse width

Tags: .net, vb.net, drawing, system.drawing

I'm programming a paint program.

When the user draws a line, I use this code, and it works as expected.

```
_Pen = New Drawing.Pen(_Color, _sngThickness)
_Pen.StartCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
_Pen.EndCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round

Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp)
    modControls.GraphicsSetSmoothingMode(g)
    g.DrawLine(_Pen, _Last.LastX, _Last.LastY, X, Y)
End Using
```

However, when the user draws a single dot and not a line, DrawLine doesn't work.
Therefore I'm using DrawEllipse.

However, the width / height of the drawn ellipse seems unpredictable and I just can't make out the correct formula. 
The single dot width / height looks like it's 80% of the line width.

This is what I'm using

```
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp)
    modControls.GraphicsSetSmoothingMode(g)
    Dim nRect As New Rectangle(X - (_sngThickness / 8), Y - (_sngThickness / 8), _sngThickness / 4, _sngThickness / 4)
    g.DrawEllipse(_Pen, nRect)
End Using
```

Does anybody seem what I'm doing wrong?

Also, my ellipse isn't filled, but I guess that's another problem.

Comment: `g.FillEllipse(...`

Comment: @LarsTech That already solved all of the strange problems. Can you make your comment the answer?

Comment: I only commented on the "that's another problem".  I'm unsure how that fixed your dimension issue.

Comment: @LarsTech I don't know as well, but with your "approach", my dimension calculations suddenly gave the correct visual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment I made, try switching to a brush instead of a pen and use the FillEllipse method instead:

```vb
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp)
  modControls.GraphicsSetSmoothingMode(g)
  Dim nRect As New Rectangle(X - (_sngThickness / 2), Y - (_sngThickness / 2),
                             _sngThickness, _sngThickness)
  g.FillEllipse(_Brush, nRect)
End Using
```

Comment: Please use / 2 instead of / 8 and / 1 instead of / 4. That's what I meant by "strange problems". I only introduced / 8 because the usual approach of / 2 wouldn't result in the correct size.